# Haskell error with a replicate-like function

Tags: haskell, replicate

I want to write a replicate-like function that works like this :

> repli "the" 3 = "ttthhheee"  and
>   repli "jason" 4 = "jjjjaaaassssoooonnnn"

Here is the code that I wrote :

```
myrepli []  n = []
myrepli [x] 0 = []
myrepli [x] n = (x:(myrepli [x] (n-1)))


repli [] n = []
repli (x:xs) n = (myrepli x n) ++ (repli xs n)
```

The error I get is this :

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `[a]' against inferred type `Char'
>      Expected type: [[a]]
>      Inferred type: [Char]
>    In the first argument of `repli', namely `"jason"'
>    In the expression: repli "jason" 3
> ```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `repli xs n = concatMap (replicate n) xs = flip (concatMap . replicate) xs n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myrepli` is expecting a *list* and an integer. However, the definition of `repli` calls it with `x`, which is an item, not a *list* of items.

I imagine you *either* want to change `myrepli` to take a single item as argument, *or* you want to change `repli` to pass `[x]` instead of just `x`. (I would suggest the former rather than the latter.)

Answer (score 8):

For problems with types, here's a trick that has helped me immensely. Whenever I am completely baffled by a message like this, I do the following:

- If there's a type signature on the function in question, remove it and see if anything changes. If it compiles, ask ghci what the type is (using `:t`). If it doesn't compile, at least the error message may differ enough to give you another clue.
- If there's no type signature, add one. Even if it doesn't compile, the error message may give you another clue.
- If that doesn't help, then temporarily add type declarations on each of the expressions in the function. (Often you'll need to break up some of the expressions to see what's really going on. You may also need to temporarily enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` pragma.) Compile again and check the error messages.

That last one is more work, but I've learned a lot from that exercise. It usually pinpoints the exact place where there's a mismatch between what I think the type is and what GHC thinks the type is.

So let's begin by adding type signatures to your code:

```
myrepli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
myrepli []  n = []
myrepli [x] 0 = []
myrepli [x] n = (x:(myrepli [x] (n-1)))


repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
repli [] n = []
repli (x:xs) n = (myrepli x n) ++ (repli xs n) -- triggers a compiler error
```

Ah, now we get a compiler error:

```
amy.hs:9:27:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[a]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a] at amy.hs:7:10
    In the first argument of `myrepli', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `(++)', namely `(myrepli x n)'
    In the expression: (myrepli x n) ++ (repli xs n)
```

The problem is in the call to `myrepli x n`. The function `myrepli` expects a list/string, but you're passing it a single character. Change that last line to:

```
repli (x:xs) n = (myrepli [x] n) ++ (repli xs n)
```

At that point you will find other errors in your code. But rather than fix your code, let me show you another way to do it:

```
repl (x:xs) n = (myReplicate x n) ++ (repl xs n)
repl [] _ = []

-- You could use the library function "replicate" here, but as a
-- learning exercise, we'll write our own.
myReplicate a n = take n (repeat a)
```

Comment: A shorter final solution: `repl xs n = xs >>= (replicate n)` (you can replace `replicate` by `myReplicate` if you want to).

Comment: or `repl xs n = concatMap (replicate n) xs`

Comment: Or you can go with the point free version `repl = (=<<) . replicate` if you swap the order of the arguments (i.e. `repl 3 "the"`).

Comment: From the question, I suspect that Jason is somewhat of a beginner to Haskell. He might not have learned about point-free notation or the bind operator yet.

Comment: @mhwombat, about your first point - the funny thing about the haskell compiler is, if you have a type signature on a function and it errors out, it doesn't say that your signature is wrong but that your program is wrong and takes the signature to be correct! So, we remove signatures to see if it compiles! :-)